# android - How to make RelativeLayout under WebView

Tags: android

I'm a beginner android developer. I have a webview in SwipeRefreshLayout in DrawerLayout. It is very hard... I need to horizontal RelativeLayout under my webview with button "left", " refresh" and edittext.

Here is my code:

```
     <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Layout Main -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">         
        <!-- WebView -->            
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/refresher"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivty"
        >
        <WebView android:id="@+id/wv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            /> 
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>                     
        <!--Bar -->

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wv_back"
                android:background="@drawable/wv_back_bg"
                android:src="@drawable/wv_left_icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/wv_back_bg"
            android:id="@+id/loading" 
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:src="@drawable/wv_refresh_icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Navigation Drawer-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingLeft="3sp"
            android:paddingRight="3sp"
            android:listSelector="#C2C2C2"
    />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!-- BlackList for Night Mode       -->

     <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll_bg"
  >
 </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

The panel covers part webview. It is necessary that she was just under it. How to make cool? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- WebView -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/refresher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/button_bar"
                tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivty">

            <WebView android:id="@+id/wv"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


        <!--Bar -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/wv_back"
                    android:background="@drawable/wv_back_bg"
                    android:src="@drawable/wv_left_icon"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            />

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/wv_back"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/loading"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/loading"
                    android:background="@drawable/wv_back_bg"
                    android:src="@drawable/wv_refresh_icon"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/refresher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivty">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"/>

              <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

             <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Left"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Refresh"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Edit Text"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Your requirement is, you have to place 3 buttons under the webview. I hope it will solve the problem.....

Comment: @sabari, interface very-very bad... Errors... Swiperefreshlayout always active... In every place page.

Comment: Oh really, Sorry for that.

Comment: @sabary, how to make hide bar if user scroll webview bottom and show if user scroll webview top?

Comment: Sorry I didnt got you, Could you update/share your code?. I will try it my side and let you know

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:background="@null"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:background="@null"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/buttons" />

</RelativeLayout>
```